# What is the purpose of Capistrano staging

Tags: capistrano

I realize I'm probably a little late to this topic but I'm trying to understand the purpose of staging with Capistrano. I see many messages of people having trouble with staging but nothing (including the Capistrano documentation) explaining why one might want to use multi-staging.

I've used Capistrano 2 many years ago but never used multistaging. Is it the recommended way now to deploy in stages?

Answer (score 0):

For my applications I use "beta", "staging" and "production". On "beta" I have a limited amount of users to test new functions. If it is working without any issues I put the application on the staging server with a broader audience. And if it succeeds I put it to production.

In Capistrano 3 you have build in multi-staging and stages are created during setup. In Capistrano you have to use the [multi-staging extension](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension).